# FInd Element and Click. If Not Found goto next page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

Hi i have the following code for the elements in page 1.

```
<span _ngcontent-iyc=""class="ng-star-inserted">ELEMENT 1</span>
<span _ngcontent-iyc=""class="ng-star-inserted">ELEMENT 2</span>
<span _ngcontent-iyc=""class="ng-star-inserted">ELEMENT 3</span>
<span _ngcontent-iyc=""class="ng-star-inserted">ELEMENT 4</span>
```

Similarly i have 4 more pages containing different elements.

What i need is to find an element using selenium python, if the element is present in that page then click on it. otherwise click on next page, search for the element there till i find the element.

The code i tried is :

```
elxpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Element 20')]"
while True:
    time.sleep(5)

        if (driver.find_element_by_xpath(elxpath)):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(elxpath).click()
            break
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to goto next page").click()
            break
```

but this code works fine with the elements in the 1st page. if the condition is false its not clicking on the next page.

The error im getting :
**Message: no such element:Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'Element 20')]"}**

Is there any other way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```py
elxpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Element 20')]"
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(elxpath).click()
        break
    except Exception:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to goto next page").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_element_by_` will return the element or will throw `NoSuchElementException` if the element not found, the `if` won't work here.

Use `find_elements_by_` to get a list of elements and check if it's not empty

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(elxpath)
if elements:
    elements[0].click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much...!! ``find_elements_by_ `` worked.

Answer (score 0):

better use `try` and `except`

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

elxpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Element 20')]"
while True:
    time.sleep(5)

        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(elxpath).click()
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to goto next page").click()
            break
```